# Does jooq offer a class similar with DataTable in C# to load data from ad-hoc queries?

Tags: java, sql, datatable, jooq, cachedrowset

Does jooq support running ad-hoc queries? I was wondering if it provides a data structure, similar with the C# DataTable (or the java CachedRowSet) where I can store the data from a query and which would support the different RDBMSes features such as Oracle cursor columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Does jooq support running ad-hoc queries?

Yes. Most of jOOQ is about running ad-hoc queries.

> I was wondering if it provides a data structure, similar with the C# DataTable (or the java CachedRowSet) where I can store the data from a query and which would support the different RDBMSes features such as Oracle cursor columns comes to mind.

No, that's currently not supported but if I understand you correctly, it is on the roadmap:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1846

Comment: Just to make sure, when I say support "ad-hoc" queries, I mean support running queries whose structure is available at runtime only. Tools such as sql studio, toad etc. they all support ad-hoc queries. They allow users to run any query. I didn't read the jooq documentation thoroughly but the samples I've seen assumed that you know the tables structures.

Comment: @costa: [Yes, those kinds of "ad-hoc" queries are supported too](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder), just like [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql)

Comment: Could you please point me to a sample? I want see how you guys retrieve the data in this case and how the fields are accessed when you don't know the columns at the time of writing the code. I couldn't find a clear example in the documentation.Thank you

Comment: @costa: The [first link](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder) makes use of inlined strings, but you can have those strings as external sources as well. Also, there's a *["model API"](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl/)* which allows you build more complex dynamic SQL... Not sure how I can further help here in the comments. Perhaps, you ask another specific question on Stack Overflow, explaining exactly the use-case you're looking for?